# Consumer surplus at equilibrium with WTP table

Tags: microeconomics, consumer-surplus, equilibrium

[image]
I should be grateful for a breakdown of the steps I should take into account. The answer is (D).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client $i$ will purchase so long as their consumer surplus is positive, i.e. so long as $$CS_i=WTP_i-75000\geq 0.$$

Once you have determined which clients $i$ satisfy this condition, you can just calculate  $CS_i$ for each such client and add them up.